# Awful looking custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a problem with custom transition between controllers. I have two view controllers. First is a table view controller and initiate controller is the second one. It has a button on it's top left corner which, when it is pressed, first navigation controller is called. There should be slide animation, but from left to right, not from right to left. I made my own transition but when the button is pressed, transition looks very awful. Transition code:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.45;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
transition.type = kCATransitionFromLeft;
[transition setType:kCATransitionPush];
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

This is a screenshot, how the transition looks like:

[image]

Comment: so.. what's the question?

Comment: I want to have normal smooth animation. Where can be the problem?

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/